Page keeps loading but data do not render from the API
Using Next.js and integrating with an API. I am able to get some search data from the api but to get further information from the api, when a link is clicked and goes to another component that is suppose to have the API data, the page keeps loading but data do not render. I am using APP Router for Nextjs.
<Link href= "/recipedetail" passHref> takes to the page , where it is referenced in page.tsx .
Code for the page suppose to have the API data
import { useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

interface Recipe {
  uri: string;
  label: string;
  image: string;
  ingredientLines: string[];
}

const RecipeDetail = () => {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const uri = searchParams.get('uri');
  const [recipe, setRecipe] = useState<Recipe | null>(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchRecipe = async (uri: string) => {
      try {
        const encodedUri = encodeURIComponent(uri);
        const apiUrl = `https://api.edamam.com/api/recipes/v2/by-uri?type=public&uri=${encodedUri}&app_id=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_ID}&app_key=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_KEY}`;

        console.log('Fetching recipe from:', apiUrl);

        const response = await axios.get(apiUrl);
        console.log('API Response:', response.data);

        setRecipe(response.data.recipe);
        setLoading(false);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching recipe details:', error);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };

    if (uri) {
      console.log('URI parameter:', uri);
      fetchRecipe(uri);
    }
  }, [uri]);

  if (loading) return <div>Loading...</div>;

  if (!recipe) return <div>Page Not Found</div>;

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{recipe.label}</h1>
      <img src={recipe.image} alt={recipe.label} />
      <p>{recipe.ingredientLines.join(', ')}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default RecipeDetail;


Are you sure you're receiving a uri on searchParams.get('uri')? Because if it's stuck on loading, according to your code, is not executing fetchRecipe and this is only possible if there's no uri
